# How to use Join in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models

Hi I have three models ,

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    subscriberId = models.SmallIntegerField(null= True,unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.subscriberId)

class Text(models.Model):
    subscriberId = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, null=False)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=162 ,blank= True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.subscriberId)

class Text2(models.Model):
    subscriberId = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, null=False)
    Du = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.subscriberId))
```

I have to get data from Text and Text2 for a particular subscriber.
In mysql I am using

```
select * from Server_Text JOIN (Server_Text2) ON (Server_Text.subscriberId_id = 11 and Server_Text2.subscriberId_id = 11) ;
```

where Server is my database name, it is working fine.

How can I use this in Django.

Comment: Do you have any query that you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

The Django-ish way of doing that is to [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related). However this won't be one SQL query:

```
subscriber = Subscriber.objects.prefetch_related('text_set', 'text2_set').get(pk=1)
print subscriver.text_set    # list of Text models
print subscriver.text2_set   # list of Text2 models
```

Comment: Tried this by  doing  subscriber = Subscriber.objects.prefetch_related('text_set', 'text2_set').get(subscriberId=1)   Facing error

Comment: Actually I want to get Everything available for a particular subscriber which is present in database and send it to html page.

Comment: The code above already is retrieving Subscriber and all of it's Text and Text2 models at once.

Comment: this is the actually query which i want to run in django  :  select * from expServer_call JOIN (expServer_sms) ON (expServer_call.subscriberId_id = 1 and expServer_sms.subscriberId_id =1)

Comment: If you have a ForeignKey on sms to the subsciber model, then you can fetch both at once using `select_related()` like that: `Text.objects.select_related('subscriber').get(pk=1)`